# If bot is in the channel, ignore the join command

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot and I came across a problem, if I type `$join` into chat, I want the bot to join the voice channel I'm in and play a sound. That is working but when the bot is already in the voice channel and I type `$join` again, it just plays the sound again and I want it to play the sound only once when it connects to the channel. I tried to solve it with some if, else and return functions but it didn't work, thanks for help.

This is my code working like I described.

```js
message.delete({
  timeout: 5000
})
const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel
if (voiceChannel) {
  const connection = await voiceChannel.join()
  const dispatcher = connection.play("./sounds/xxx.mp3")
  dispatcher.setVolume(0.5)
} else {
  message.reply("you need to be in a voice channel!").then(message => {
    message.delete({
      timeout: 5000
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether the channel of your voice connection is the same you're about to join: if so, you don't need to do anything (you're already in the channel), otherwise you join, make the sound etc...
You can do this with [`VoiceConnection.channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection?scrollTo=channel)

Here's how I would do it:

```js
const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel
if (voiceChannel) { 
  // Check if any of the ALREADY EXISTING connections are in that channel, if not connect
  if (!client.voice.connections.some(conn => conn.channel.id == voiceChannel.id)) {
    const connection = await voiceChannel.join()
    const dispatcher = connection.play("./sounds/xxx.mp3")
    dispatcher.setVolume(0.5)
  } // else: you're already in the channel
} else {
  let m = await message.reply("You need to be in a voice channel!")
  m.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I'm trying to do, I want the bot to make a sound when I put it to the same voice channel as me by typing $join command, but my problem is that when I type $join again when bot is already in the voice channel, it makes the sound again, but I don't want that.

Comment: I know that you only want the sound not to happen, but you can see how joining the channel when you already know that the bot is already there is pointless. The code from my answer is meant to show you that there is a way to make the sound only when you're joining a new channel (`voiceChannel.id != connection.channel.id`), if you want you can make it do only that. I don't think I have misunderstood your question, I just think that this way has more sense: if you disagree, the only thing that you need is the bit from the `if` statement

Comment: Unfortunately, after I tried your method it still doesn't work. I will do it somehow else, but thanks for help.

Comment: Which part doesn't work? If you tell me we can fix it for everyone

Comment: In your code, I had to put the `const connection = await voiceChannel.join()` before the `if` statement, because it was called before initalization. Now when I type $join into chat, the bot replies `"you need to be in a voice channel!"`.

Comment: Well, that's fair ahaha. I've edited my answer, it should work now

Comment: Now it connects to the channel, the green circle around profile picture appears, but it doesn't play anything.

Comment: @Joneh Maybe now it's ok: it finds whether any of the existing voice connections is in that channel, if not you connect and play the sound

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much, now it is working exactly as I wanted.

Comment: Perfect! Happy to hear that :)